# What does "with probability $1 - \delta$" mean in optimization theorems for algorithms?

Tags: probability, optimization, convex-optimization

I´m reading a paper about second order stochastic optimization. In many of their theories it states that the convergence rate or other inequalities hold "with probability $1 - \delta$" or "with probability at least $1 - \delta$.

For example one theorem states: Algorithm 1 returns a point $x_t$ such that with probability at least $1 - \delta$: $f(x_t) \leq f(x^{*}) + \epsilon$.

How do I show that it holds "with probability at least $1 - \delta$" ? Do I have to show that $\Pr\left(f(x_t) \leq f(x^{*}) + \epsilon\right) \geq 1 - \delta$ ? How can I do that exactly?

Or is there similar material where I can look up on how to show this?

For more context if needed, the above theorem is given on page 11 here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.03943.pdf.

Any answer is appreciated!

Comment: I am also kind of confused by the statement "Do I have to show that [...]". In the linked paper (well, it's a paper, with proofs), the authors *do* show it. (In the proof of Theorem 3.3, which uses Lemma 3.5, where a high probability statement is made and shown by calling Lemma 3.6).

Comment: Why did you delete the statement of your question?

Answer (score 2):

The algorithms are described as "stochastic". This means that there will be inherent randomness in the algorithm. As such, it's possible that the algorithm will fail, but this probability is at most $\delta$. So yes, you need to show exactly the probability inequality that you have stated.
Without reading the paper more thoroughly I can't say where this probability will arrive.

---

**Edit** As pointed out by Clement C. in the comments below, the randomness comes the middle step of the algorithm, which states "Sample $\tilde{\nabla}^2 f_{[i,j]}(\mathbf{x}_t)$ uniformly from [...]".
See in particular Lemma 3.6 and its proof, where it explicitly states
$$ \Pr[ \| \tilde{\nabla}^{-2} f(\mathbf{x}_t) - \nabla^{-2} f(\mathbf{x}_t)\|  \leq \gamma ]\geq 1- \delta. $$
(This information from this edit is given by Clement C.'s comments, but I am collecting it here for readability.)

Comment: The randomness arises from the middle step, which states" Sample $\tilde{\nabla}^2 f_{[i,j]}(\mathbf{x}_t)$  uniformly from [...]."

Comment: Thank you for the answers.  Do you know what the next steps would be to show this inequality? It looks to me I have to use the matrix bernstein inequality that is given on page 9 (theorem 2.1) but i don't know how exactly.

Comment: @Sorancon Read the proof of Theorem 3.3 (the statement is given, but _also_ the proof!). It invokes Lemma 3.6, which is the where this concentration statement is proven. (The proof of Lemma 3.6 is on p.13).

Comment: Sorry for asking again. I have read the proof to theorem 3.3 and also the one to lemma 3.6. But how can I use Lemma 3.6 to show my original inequality $\Pr\left(f(x_t) \leq f(x^{*}) + \epsilon\right) \geq 1 - \delta$ ? I don't see the connection.

Comment: Lemma 3.6 is used in the proof of Lemma 3.5, which itself is used in the proof of Theorem 3.3. In Lemma 3.5, Lemma 3.6 is directly invoked to bound "$\| b\|$" (with a bound that holds w.p. at least $1-\delta$), since (recalling what $\gamma$) Lemma 3.6 literally states that $$\Pr[ \| \tilde{\nabla}^{-2} f(\mathbf{x}_t) - \nabla^{-2} f(\mathbf{x}_t)\| ] \leq \gamma ]\geq 1- \delta$$ @Sorancon

Comment: Okay, then I understand that theorem 3.3 holds with probability at least $1-\delta$  because of Lemma 3.6 (specifically because of the inequality you stated). So that means that Corollary 3.4 also holds with probability at least $1-\delta$ because we use theorem 3.3. Is that correct?

Comment: @Sorancon Yes. Corollary 3.4 is a corollary: i.e., a direct (and supposedly straightforward) consequence of Theorem 3.3.

Comment: The reason this is a corollary is that if you run the algorithm for $t=1,\dots,T=\ln(1/\varepsilon)$ ($\ln(1/\varepsilon)$ steps), then by Theorem 3.3 with probability at least $1-\delta$ you divide the distance to $\mathbf{x}^\ast$ at *every* step, and thus at step $T$ you are at distance at most $1/2^T = \varepsilon$ from  $\mathbf{x}^\ast$. @Sorancon (the stated time complexity also follows from the step-wise time complexity of Theorem 3.3, multiplied by $T$ (since we have $T$ steps).